# Ignition coil upgrade

Tags: motorcycle, ignition, sparkplugs, ignition-coil, spark-plug-wires

My motorcycle felt unresponsive these past few days and found out that it was caused by a weak spark because the ignition coil is about to go bust.

Since I am thinking about doing an upgrade to a performance ignition coil, my concern are as follows:
1. As this is a commuter bike, will it have an effect on reliability and durability?
2. Will a replacement be required for the stock CDI to a new performance CDI?

Thanks.

Comment: If it's a commuter bike you likely aren't going to see the benefits of a performance col.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should reconsider the "upgrade" part of your sentence. 
For a commuter bike it will make no special difference to upgrade only the ignition so i believe you would be better of to target quality instead of performance. Try to replace them with your stock parts or at least try to find the exact same part in Bosch or Denso make. 
For your no2 question most of the new aftermarket coils have slightly different specs so you if you decide to change them you should (not certainly but) probably change your CDI along to prevent any faulty behavior.

Comment: Thanks. The stock IG coil only gives out 10kv, while the performance replacement that I am looking in to gives out 3x of that. I’m wondering if the extra power will benefit responsiveness. For durability, one of my buddies has it on his bike but the setup was more of a super stock.